# "Map to Local Folder" option missing in VS2008

Tags: version-control, tfs, team-explorer

A colleague has installed VS2008 Team Explorer (as part of his role in Scrum) and can successfully use Work Items, Documents and Reports. I now want him to use the TFS Source Control for non-code files (documents etc). He can successfully open Source Control Explorer but everything is greyed out as nothing has been mapped locally. Unfortunately, the "Map to Local Folder" option is missing from the context menus.

Is there another component he needs to install in order to use the Source Control part of TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he installs [SP1 of Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E) he'll find it much easier to use.  SP1 includes things like drag-drop into Source Control Explorer to add files, easier local folder mapping and links to open the local folder in windows explorer from the source control explorer.

You might also want him to install the [TFS 2008 Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) - especially the Windows Shell Extensions (not selected by default in the installer) as they make it easier to deal with files outside of Visual Studio.  This is very handy for word docs etc.

Comment: We're installing them now. However, I find myself sceptical that a service pack would add functionality that would block the original application from functioning.

Comment: Martin is 100% right.  "Map to local folder" is a very recent addition to the context menu.  Previously, all changes to your workspace mappings had to be done from the main Edit Workspace dialog (accessed via the dropdown in SCE or the File -> Source Control menu).

Comment: @Chris - It is still possible to do in 2008 without the service pack, just hard.  Basically you go to File, Source Control, Workspaces and edit the workspace form there to add the working folder mapping.  Alternatively you would do a Get Latest on the folder and when you do that for a folder that is not mapped it will prompt you where you would like it to be downloaded - setting up a working folder mapping for you in the process.

Comment: In hindsight I should have been more specific with my question. It should have read: "How do I map source control to local folders in VS2008".